# How can I get process.env.PORT from a bash script for cloud9?

Tags: node.js, bash, smalltalk

first the basic question, below the context:

Note: I am using c9.io, the paid cloud9 service, not my own rollout of cloud9.

I am trying to get the port that would be returned from "process.env.PORT" in nodejs while running on cloud9.  This is the way you would run a nodejs application on cloud9 instead of specifying a port number directly.

However, I don't want to modify my fileserver.js code for various reasons.  I do however have the option of specifying a port as an argument on the command line that invokes fileserver.js.

So - how do I get the same port that process.env.PORT would return in a nodejs app from within a bash script?

Note, I have already tried $PORT - which returns 8080 (not correct).

Context:

I'm trying to run an amber smalltalk FileServer from within cloud9.  Modifying the FileServer.js file is probably not an elegant solution as I will have to do it every time it is changed in the amber smalltalk git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$PORT gives you the variable `PORT` from current shell environment. It could be different for the process. 
To get the variables from the started server's environment you must know its pid. Then you can run

```
cat /proc/pid/environ
//or more readable
xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/pid/environ
```

Replace `pid` with the value of server process's pid. You can then extract the PORT variable from above.

Comment: If you specify the port number on the command line, use this technique on `/proc/pid/cmdline` to extract the port number